# Yii: common entry point

Tags: php, yii, statistics, entry-point

I would like to log which users visited the site today. To do this I have to handle user visit at any page I have on the site.

What is common entry point (code, which executes on any visit to any page)?

Comment: `index.php` is what everything gets directed to by .htaccess

Answer (score 4):

Also you can create class BaseController extends CController, and use init method. For example:

```
    class BaseController extends CController
    {
        public function init()
        {
            $this->loggedUserId    = Yii::app()->user->getId();
            $this->isLogged        = !empty($this->loggedUserId);

            if ($this->isLogged) {
                // some log actions
            }

            return parent::init();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess if you want to log which users visited site then you should implement this functionality in `user` component (`CWebUser` by default). You can extends this calss and specify it in config for user component:

```
'user'=>array(
    // enable cookie-based authentication
    'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    'class'=>'MyWebUser',
),
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I execute some code, when user requests page from site?

Comment: @DenisKulagin for example as follows: `public function init(){
   parent::init();
   //your code here
}` and call logging method there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about Yii 1.1

There are [onBeginRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onBeginRequest-detail) and [onEndRequest](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onEndRequest-detail) events you could attach your logic on:

Example (in an appropiate file, index.php/custom loader script, simple)

```
Yii::app()->onBeginRequest = function(CEvent $event) { handle_event($event); };
```

Or attach a custom behaviour to that event in your config:

```
'behaviors' => array(
    'onbeginRequest' => array(
        'class' => 'application.components.AnalyticsBehaviour',
    )
)
```

and handle in the behaviour.